# Resources created by azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment are not detecting differences

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
Terraform v0.14.7
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.44.0
```

I'm running into a problem with resources created via azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment. I have some web apps with virtual paths and these virtual paths are created by the azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment. If I go to Azure Portal and delete the web app, and then run terraform apply to recreate these resources, the web app is created fine, but the virtual paths are not. It seems like Terraform is not detecting these missing virtual paths. I've filed an [issue on Github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11414) but the maintainers have marked it as a question, so I'm not sure if I'll get a response there.

Has anyone else noticed this problem before? I thought Terraform would be able to detect differences and apply what is missing. If I mark these resources as tainted, Terraform can't even destroy them. I get this error:

`Error: removing items provisioned by this Template Deployment: deleting Nested Resource "/subscriptions/000-000-000-000/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/api/slots/staging/config/web": pollingTrackerBase#updateRawBody: failed to unmarshal response body: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value`

Here is the terraform configuration

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "api_virtual_directory" {
  name                = "api_virtual_directory"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.digital.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  template_content    = <<TEMPLATE
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "webAppName": {
        "type": "String",
        "defaultValue": "${module.webapp["api"].name}"
    },
    "virtualApplications":{
      "type": "Array",
      "defaultValue":[
        {
        "virtualPath": "/",
        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
        "preloadEnabled": false,
        "virtualDirectories": null
        },
        {
        "virtualPath": "/app1",
        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot\\app1",
        "preloadEnabled": false,
        "virtualDirectories": null
        },
        {
        "virtualPath": "/app2",
        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot\\app2",
        "preloadEnabled": false,
        "virtualDirectories": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/web')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "properties": {
          "virtualApplications": "[parameters('virtualApplications')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
TEMPLATE
  depends_on          = [module.webapp["api"]]
}
```